# Annotate an image in tkinter canvas window dynamically

Tags: tkinter, tkinter-canvas, tkinter-layout

So I am displaying an image using canvas in my Tkinter window. Now I have a button which calculates certain parameters and I want that to be displayed dynamically over the image. So basically after each calculation, the annotations should change to new parameters.

e.g. Consider that I am calculating column dimensions, and after each calculation, I have to display the dimensions marked on the respective sides of the column image that I have in my Tkinter window.

So is it possible to annotate the image dynamically and if not, is there any other way to perform this task?

Comment: Have you tried to place the image on the canvas then create the annotations over it? If you can do that and you want to update the annotations just delete the sprite and create the new annotations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the below example out

```py
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image,ImageTk
import random

def annotate():
    annotation=str(random.randint(1000,9999))
    canvas.itemconfig(annotation_text,text=annotation)

root=Tk()

canvas=Canvas(root)
canvas.pack(fill='both',expand=True)

image=Image.open('example.png')
image=ImageTk.PhotoImage(image.resize((300,300)))
canvas.create_image(150,150,image=image)

annotation_text=canvas.create_text(50,50,text='')

button=Button(root,text='Annotate',command=annotate)
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

You can make use of the `itemconfig` method to configure the text. The above example will annotate the image at `(50,50)` with a random integer on click of a button.

Comment: Thanks that helped, btw is there any way we can do this in real-time, like simultaneously while I am entering the value, without the need to press the button?

Comment: There are multiple ways to do it, I think the easiest one would be to use `widget.bind('<Key>',update)` where `update` is the function that fetches the value and updates the item.